# Will a loading indicator over a content before bootstrapping an app will affect my SEO?

Tags: seo

I built a landing page using Angular. Since you may know, without Client/Server-side rendering, crawlers can't obtain any data since all the dom is being manipulated by Javascript.

Therefore, I prerendered my app so it would be possible for crawlers to obtain my app's data.

So far so good.

My landing page starts with intro animations right at the start. And I've noticed that it happens twice (first because of the prerender, and second because the app has beinng bootstrapped).

After some research, I couldn't find a solution for it, so I thought maybe I should put a placeholder (a loading indicator) over the animation (which has content such as H1) as long as the app hasn't being prerendered.

My question is, will it impact my SEO? the loading indicator should be presented for like 0~1s after full reload.

*disclaimer: got redirected from stackoverflow to webmaster. If the question doesn't belong here, do tell.*

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! You are in the right place. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought question cause without seeing it it's difficult to provide an answer.

In first place, you should use [Search Console Inspector tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en) to analyze how Google sees your home and what kind of information is available for the searcher.

Having that in mind you can check if that info is what you want Google to see or if you need to provide more content in order to properly rank and avoid problems.

If it is possible, I'll recommend you to use [dynamic rendering](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering) in order to provide Google a full SEO optimized home.

[image]